# Set -vm in eclipse.ini on MacOs without setting path

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I don't want to install JDK. I have a complete JDK that I unzipped from a tar file (Azul JDK).

```
-vm
/Users/myusername6/Desktop/IF/zulu10.3+5-jdk10.0.2-macosx_x64/bin/java
```

When I set -vm option in eclipse.ini, it says you have to install java. It seems that eclipse is not picking up my java location.

When I go to location where ~/bin/java is present and when I type in java -version, I see an error on the terminal. But when I type ./java -version, this works.

My first priority is to not set the path. So I can switch to different implementations easily. Is it possible to run eclipse without installing jdk or setting path?

Comment: Where exactly in the eclipse.ini did you put the -vm? It must come **before** any -vmargs line.

Comment: It is the very first command. Before --startup

Comment: I resolved this issue by just installing jdk for the time being. @greg-449 thank you for looking into it.